# Java generic parameters and interface extension

Tags: java, generics

I have an interface like so

```java
public interface A {}
```

and an interface which extends from the previous like so

```java
public interface B extends A {}
```

The constructor of one of my classes takes as parameter a `Function<A, String>` object. Within the constructor, several objects which implement `A` are passed into said function to generate a string.

I would like to be able to pass this constructor a `Function<B, String>` object, as all classes that implement `B` implement `A` by extension. However, when attempting to do this, I am told "Incompatible types: A is not convertible to B". Which I don't understand as I am trying to convert `B` to `A` not `A` to `B`

I have tried changing the parameter type from a `Function<A, String>` to a

```java
Function<? extends A, String>
```

but alas this doesn't work either.

Is there some way I can achieve passing either a `Function<A, String>` or a `Function<B, String>` into the same argument?

I am creating a game using the Swing library, and my `A` is `Displayable` and `B` is `Purchasable`. I have a class `DisplayablePanel` which extends `JPanel` and creates a visual representation of any displayable object in my game. All `Purchasables` are `Displayable` so I can display them using my `DisplayPanel` however, I want `Purchasables` to be able to display `Purchasable` specific information too. Here my constructor uses the `Function<A, String>` to decide what text should be displayed on a button that sits on the `DisplayPanel` And for my `Purchasable`s this information is specific to the `Purchasable` interface

Comment: Could you show a concrete example of what you're trying to do? That is, a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. It's hard to glean what the code is like from a description and much better to see the code itself.

Comment: If you've got a function that operates on a `B`, how do you expect your constructor to be able to call it on a bunch of objects that implement `A`, and don't necessarily implement `B`?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I suppose you're right I hadn't thought about that. My constructor will be passing objects which will implement `A` but not necessarily `B` and so my function which does need objects to implement `B` would not accept an `A`

Comment: It's possible that your class should be a generic - `YourClass<T extends A>`, so that you can have a `YourClass<A>` whose constructor takes a `Function<A, String>`, and a `YourClass<B>` whose constructor takes a `Function<B, String>` and executes it on a bunch of objects that implement `B`.  But I can't tell from your question whether that meets your requirements.

Comment: This is strongly related to [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super) (bordeline duplicate). It sounds like you're not writing a collection, but Java can't know that, so it has to apply PECS semantics to all generics.

Comment: @yshavit Just stumbled across PECS whilst doing some research on `<? super T>`. Trying to figure out how this applies to my problem

Comment: If your function takes a parameter of type `A`, then it's **c**onsuming a value of type `A`. That's the "C" in "PECS", so you should use `super`.

Comment: (and if that doesn't work for your use case, then as @DawoodibnKareem said, you _probably_ need to make the class generic.)

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem This seems like my way forward. Not 100% comfortable with using generics as they make things a little more tricky but will be an interesting learning experience I suppose

Answer (score 2):

> s there some way I can achieve passing either a Function<A, String> or a Function<B, String> into the same argument?

Sure:

```
public void heyNow(Function<? super B, String> func) {
  B b = createAnInstanceOfSomethingImplementingB();
  String answer = func.apply(b);
}
```

That works fine.

Generics are **invariant** - in plain jane java, `Number n = new Integer(10);` is fine. In generics, it is not; `ArrayList<Number> x = new ArrayList<String>();` doesn't compile because it shouldn't: After all, you can do this:

```
void foo(List<Number> list) {
  Number n = 5; // n is an integer.
  list.add(n); // this has to work, right?
}
```

So now we just added an integer. Imagine we invoked foo, passing in a `new ArrayList<Double>()`. We just.... added an integer.... to a list of doubles.

Oh dear.

This is why generics are invariant. Because the concept inherently is.

This is what `<? extends>` and `<? super>` are all about: You add some handcuffs to the method (`<? extends>` means: Can't invoke `add`, `<? super>` means: when invoking `get()`, just get `Object` back, that's all, i.e. not very useful, i.e. can't usefully invoke `get`), in trade for allowing different things in the `<>` to be passed along.

Comment: Changing the parameter to type`Function<? super B, String> func` makes the output of `func.apply(a)` `Object` But how does this make sense as the return type of the function referenced by `func` is specified as `String` by the generic type argument?

Comment: It compiles fine for me as having a `String` result: `void use(Function<? super B, String> f) { String s = f.apply(null); }`

Comment: @Harry no, it doesn't - `the `apply()` function of a `Function<? super B, String>` requires that you pass in a B (so, `new B()`, or `new SomeSubTypeOfB()`), and it returns a `String`.

Comment: @rzwitserloot yeah sorry didn't realize that I'd bumped a button in IntelliJ that changed the return type for some reason :/